# python pandas date time output dates the same

Tags: python

The purpose of this code is to read a CSV file, the file has five columns ['Release Date', 'Time', 'Actual', 'Forecast', 'Previous'], and the 'Release Date' column has two shapes of dates:

• Sep 09, 2018 (Aug)

• Sep 24, 2018

So I can NOT simply scrape dates because of the mismatched date shape, so I decided to create a new column based on 'Release Date', 'Time' columns then add it to the original data frame.

I tried this code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Sayed\Desktop\script\data.csv")
for date, time in zip(df['Release Date'], df['Time']):
    Date = date[:12] + ' ' + time
    df['Date'] = Date
print(df.head())
```

But I got this output:

Release Date   Time Actual Forecast Previous Date

Oct 15, 2018 (Sep)  21:30            0.5%     0.7%  Feb 01, 1996 05:00

Sep 09, 2018 (Aug)  21:30   0.7%     0.5%     0.3%  Feb 01, 1996 05:00

Aug 08, 2018 (Jul)  21:30   0.3%     0.2%    -0.1%  Feb 01, 1996 05:00

Jul 09, 2018 (Jun)  21:30  -0.1%     0.1%    -0.2%  Feb 01, 1996 05:00

Jun 08, 2018 (May)  21:30  -0.2%    -0.1%    -0.2%  Feb 01, 1996 05:00

Comment: You didn't tell us what the original data looked like.

Comment: @IMCoins the same but without date column

Comment: What do you want your output to look like? Also, it's not a good idea to use a loop and iterate through rows of a dataframe. Try using `df.apply` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop is wrong and unnecessary.

Try this:

```
df["Date"] = df["Release Date"].apply(lambda x: x[:12]) + " " + df["Time"]
```

Answer (score 1):

This line of code:

```
df['Date'] = Date
```

Changes EVERY row in the column 'Date' to receive the value of your last Date input, on every iteration of the loop.

Try using it as a lambda function. You'll notice a boost in performance, too:

```
def GetDate(row):
    return row['Release Date'][:12] + ' ' + row['Time']

df['Date'] = df.apply(lambda x: GetDate(x), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a fan of the `.apply()` method in pandas as it is really not efficient.

Here is another solution of mine to help you to deal with your problem efficiently. I also made a benchmark to prove that `.apply()` is really inefficient. And when it comes to Big Data, you must use it only if necessary.

```
df['Date'] = df.loc[:, 'Release Date'][:12] + ' ' + df['Time']
```

This line means : Take all the Index from 0 to 12 (excluded), from all the rows at column 'Release Date', add a space to it, add column 'Time' to it (implicitly meaning all the rows).

```
import pandas as pd
import timeit
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def IMCoins(df):
    df['Date'] = df.loc[:, 'Release Date'][:12] + ' ' + df['Time']

def petezurich(df):
    df['Date'] = df['Release Date'].apply(lambda x: x[:12]) + ' ' + df['Time']

def benchmark(x_ticks, time_arr_1, time_arr_2):
    """ Displays difference between all the time_arr.
    """
    X = range(len(time_arr_1))

    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(X, time_arr_1, marker='o', color='g', label='IMCoins')
    plt.plot(X, time_arr_2, marker='o', color='r', label='petezurich')
    plt.ylabel('Time in seconds')
    plt.xlabel('Number of elements to iterate on')
    plt.xticks( [nb for nb in range(len(x_ticks))], x_ticks, rotation=30)
    plt.legend()
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #   Iterations are the number of tests run by timeit.
    n_iter = 10

    #   Elements modifies the shape of the DataFrame
    n_elements = 10

    #   Number of time n_elements will get multiplied by factor.
    n_increase = 7
    factor = 10

    time_arr_1, time_arr_2, x_ticks = [], [], []
    for idx in range(n_increase):
        #   Preparing data inside the loop because we need to
        #   increase its size.
        data = {
            'Release Date' : ['a' * 20 for _ in range(n_elements)],
            'Time' : ['b' * 10 for _ in range(n_elements)]
        }
        df = pd.DataFrame(data)

        #   We check the both functions are giving the same results.
        assert IMCoins(df) == petezurich(df), 'results are different'

        t1 = timeit.timeit(stmt = 'IMCoins(df)',
                           setup = 'from __main__ import df, IMCoins',
                           number= n_iter)
        time_arr_1.append(t1)

        t2 = timeit.timeit(stmt = 'petezurich(df)',
                           setup = 'from __main__ import df, petezurich',
                           number = n_iter)
        time_arr_2.append(t2)

        #   We want to correctly display the number of elements computer on
        #   some later plots.
        x_ticks.append(n_elements)

        # In order to increase the data...
        n_elements *= factorx

    benchmark(x_ticks, time_arr_1, time_arr_2)
```

[image: benchmark]